# SELECT * vs SELECT Column Load Time

Tags: mysql, sql

When I was starting out I always just did SELECT * because I was afraid that if I messed around with the code in any way that I would cause an error...

Months later I realized that my website is full of SELECT *'s when a lot of the time I only need to select one column.

Will it make a noticeable difference in page load time if I reduce all the "SELECT *" to "SELECT column"?

I assume that it makes it faster, but I have no idea if it would be noticeable.

Thanks!

Comment: faster?  yes.  noticeable?  it depends...

Comment: sorry, but... it depends... on many things, basically how much extra data is coming across the wire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the amount of data that your table holds or the number of joins in your query. Definitely, select column will be faster than select *. But, the statistics absolutely depend on the data.

Also it is a bad practice. please see this question:

[Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be faster. (At the very least, you're sending less data between your RDBMS and whatever scripting language you have in use.)

As to *how* much faster, it really depends on the amount of fields/data, etc. in your database. As such, you'll need to profile your application in both states to find out. (As the old saying goes - **why estimate what you can measure?**)

Incidentally, I'd also recommend a read of the existing [What is the reason not to use select *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select) question/answers.